# Laptop hangs when I don't touch it for few seconds

Tags: linux, usb, mouse, power-management, pop-os

I noticed that when my laptop is on battery mode, when I don't interact with it (like moving my mouse - both external and trackpad, or pressing any key) for couple of seconds, it freezes. Then after I move the mouse or press a key, it wakes up and starts working normally. The problem is I face a one/two seconds delay which is pretty annoying. I don't know how to change the setting so that when laptop is not connected to power, it won't hang.

**Note**: My external mouse is a wired mouse not Bluetooth.
**Interesting Note**: When I connect my laptop to a monitor via HDMI cable, I will no longer see the issue even when it's on battery mode.

OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64
Mouse: ROG Sica
Laptop: Acer nitro 5

**Update to provide more information as requested**:

```bash
soroush@pop-os:~$ cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend 
-1
soroush@pop-os:~$ python3 Desktop/lsusb.py 
 WARNING: Failure to read usb.ids
usb1              1d6b:0002 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (xhci-hcd 0000:00:14.0) hub
  1-3               0b05:181b 00 2IFs [USB 2.00,    12 Mbps, 100mA] (ASUS ROG SICA)
  1-5               0408:a061 ef 2IFs [USB 2.01,   480 Mbps, 500mA] (SunplusIT Inc HD User Facing)
  1-14              8087:0026 e0 2IFs [USB 2.01,    12 Mbps, 100mA] ()
usb2              1d6b:0003 09 1IF  [USB 3.10, 10000 Mbps,   0mA] (xhci-hcd 0000:00:14.0) hub
soroush@pop-os:~$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:a061 Quanta Computer, Inc. HD User Facing
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:181b ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ROG SICA
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
soroush@pop-os:~$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/
1-0:1.0/  1-14:1.0/ 1-3/      1-3:1.1/  1-5:1.0/  2-0:1.0/  usb2/     
1-14/     1-14:1.1/ 1-3:1.0/  1-5/      1-5:1.1/  usb1/     
soroush@pop-os:~$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/power/control 
on
soroush@pop-os:~$
```

`lsusb -vt` output:

```bash
soroush@pop-os:~$ lsusb -vt
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        ID 0b05:181b ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        ID 0b05:181b ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0408:a061 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        ID 0408:a061 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
    |__ Port 14: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
    |__ Port 14: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
soroush@pop-os:~$
```

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for comment. Can "autosuspend" affect keyboard's key-press as well? Because I had that problem too, Looks like after few seconds *everything* is suspended... and unfortunately after trying the solutions in that link I wasn't able to solve that.

Comment: @don_crissti I first tried that but there is no such folder `1-2`. I specifically showed the result of tab completion to demonstrate that.

Comment: @don_crissti My guess is that it's not related to a specific device... It's more likely something related to power management. It suspends the entire system after a few seconds of inactivity. And only in battery mode...

Comment: Indeed, that might be the case... Looks like `1-3` was the right port for the mouse after all, as it shows in both your last edit and in the initial `lsusb.py` output and it has autosuspend disabled. Autosuspend is also disabled in the `usbcore` module so we can rule out per-device settings... it looks like something is suspending your system (or at least the usb subsystem since both mouse and keyboard are affected...) but what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mattia.b89's answer shed some light on solving the problem. He said I can try TLP for better power management.

I remember once I had battery drain problem, I saw [this page](https://support.system76.com/articles/battery/) from Pop!_OS documentation and one of the methods was using TLP!. I'm sure it was there, that's why I installed it.

But now, "*Article was last edited at 12/16/2022*" and it specifically says "Do not use TLP because it's not compatible with `system76-power`.

So the solution is simply ***uninstall TLP***!

Answer (score 4):

Issue looks like a simple **Power management** matter;
in fact, it magically disappear on power cord plug in;
and it deals with:

- hardware
- firmware
- software

for this reason, I would not *trust* the `$cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend` output;
Could be a **quirk** or **firmware/BIOS setting** which overcome any software (linux kernel and/or Pop OS) parameter...

Now, I do not use your OS/DE, so I do not know if there is a software component which take care of power management and at what depth level, but
kernel is Linux as well, so I would dive into resources e.g. archwiki **[1]**
and give a try to other software like TLP **[2]** and powertop **[3]**

---

**[1]** https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management#USB_autosuspend
**[2]** https://github.com/linrunner/TLP
**[3]** https://01.org/powertop